# How to fix: assigning argparse argument to variable assigning both argument and value to variable

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

Trying to assign argparse argument value to a variable. The variable is then assigned as "variable=argument=value" instead of just "variable=value".

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("test", help="test")
args = parser.parse_args()
variable = args.test
print(variable)
```

I expect the printed result to be what is assigned to test. Let's say the program is run as:

```
python program.py test=something
```

The printed result should then be:

```
something
```

The actual output is:

```
test=something
```

Comment: Define your argument as an `optional` taking `---test` as the flag.

Comment: I have positional arguments which have to defined to run the program. An ugly way to do it, which works but looks bad, is to do a replace as in

   variable = args.test.replace('test=','')

Comment: Or another solution - use 'python program.py something`

Comment: Don't confuse `positionals` and `optionals` in `argparse` with `positional` vs `keyword` arguments of functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-t", "--test", help="test")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)   # for debugging help
variable = args.test
print(variable)
```

test with

```
python program.py --test something
```

`parser.add_argument("test", help="test")` defines a `positional` argument, one that depends on position, or order, not a flag.  Flags look like `--test`, a common command line convention.  A positional argument does not split the input on `=` (or anything else); the whole string is the `value`.